# How to hit an AWS EC2 instance private IP from company on premise machine brwoser to access application running on the EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 with only private IP say xxx.xx.xx.xx on AWS in a private subnet. I set up an application there running on port 8080 sometime ago.
The security group, NACL, etc are all set to allow inbound on 8080 from my machine say A and an another machine say B. Both A and B are my company on premise machines. The VPC where that EC2 is hosted connects to on premise i guess via VPN->Site to Site VPN connection using virtual private gateways. I am not much into networking so do not really know how all of that is set up and works.

The issue now is that i can easily hit that ec2 private IP:8080 using the browser on machine B.
So http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/ is routable and accessible from machine B and the application renders just fine.
But if i hit the same http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080 from my machine A, it says connection refused.

What baffles me is the most obvious question as to how that works just fine from  machine B but not from my machine A.
What could be the factors that might come into play in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both machines A and B are on the same network, then the difference either comes from the machines themselves, or from a configuration that specifically permits access from machine B (the working one).

It is possible that the Amazon EC2 instance (on `xxx.xx.xx.xx`) has been configured with a **Security Group** that permits access only from a specific IP address. You should examine the Inbound configuration of all Security Groups associated with the Amazon EC2 instance.

If that is not the cause, then it would be something specific to machine A (which doesn't connect) that is causing the problem. Test by trying to connect from yet another computer (machine C) to see whether it is able to connect. If that works, then the problem definitely lies with machine A.

Comment: Thanks John! They are both on my company's network but i am not sure how to know "If both machines A and B are on the same network". The security group is just fine and inbound allows on port 8080 from entire company CIDR. I am just wondering how does one configure to enable routing from an on prem network to a private IP on AWS VPC? As i said the connection to AWS from our corporate network is via site-to-site VPN. But what i don't know is how would that apply differently for machine A and B while they are still hosted on corporate network.

Comment: If they are both "plugged into the wall", then treat them as being on the same network. Trying from a third machine will help identify whether the problem is with machine A, or a configuration that is only permitted machine B.

Comment: Looks like they are not on the same network segments and so there are explicit firewall rules only for machine B that allows it to privately route that EC2

Answer (score 0):

You can try check using *`telnet`* or *`tcptraceroute`* from machine 'A'.

Comment: It says 
Connecting To ***.**.**.**...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Comment: you can compare result telnet and tcptraceroute from machine B. Maybe any config in firewall must be check again.